# Vue: How to use javascript class in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class, getter

However, that doesn't work, and it probably isn't a good solution. How can I do it correctly? Can I use a javascript class in vuex state at all?

Getter

```
import { ChatMessage } from '~/classes/ChatMessage'

export default {
  getChatMessages: (state) => {
    const messages = _.orderBy(state.messages, 'created_at', 'asc')

    messages.forEach((message, index) => {
      const ChatMessage = new ChatMessage(message, index, messages)
      message.isNewDay = ChatMessage.idNewDay()
    })

    console.log(messages)

    return messages
  },
}
```

Class file:

```
export class ChatMessage {
  constructor(message, index, messages) {
    this.message = message
    this.index = index
    this.messages = messages
  }

  get isNewDay() {
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: You should set `message.isNewDay` when dispatch action to setup `messages`

Comment: You can, and you shouldn't because this restricts you in ways you need to design classes to keep them reactive and doesn't provide you with anything that plain objects aren't good for. `message.isNewDay` can't be set because it's read-only, there's nothing specific to Vuex